# Retrieve the help page to a file

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning selenium to parse a page

```
>>> link_elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("pager_next")
>>> type(link_elem)
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
```

In the interactive mode, the manual could be checked as:

```
>>> help(link_elem)
```

I tried to redirect it to disk as

```
>>> help(link_elem) > manual.md
NameError: name 'manual' is not defined
```

How could I retrieve the help page to a file?

Comment: `>` means "greater than" in Python, not redirect to file.

Comment: Could you share few more lines of code? Since its difficult to say or reproduce using such little code

Answer (score 2):

`>` in python is not acting like `>` in bash, to save content into a file you need to use the `open()` function. The following code does what you are trying to achieve:

```
with open("manual.md", "w") as file:
  file.write(help(link_elem))
```

Comment: Downvoted. OP wants to get the string content of help(..) out to a file.

Comment: @zhilevan 1. I don't have Python, so I can't check anything. 2. I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @UltraInstinct check it agaain

Comment: @zhilevan: Tiny bit better, but `help(..)` doesn't anything. Its meant to be used purely in interactive sessions.

Comment: @UltraInstinct it's up to Painter ( maybe it's a custom function in his code which returns markups of a page), couldn't be?

Comment: I upvoted but it not working on python 3.6 TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: @Painter would you please add your help function? it returns None . the error is because of your help function output